# CPP Visual Studio 2017 "CLR Form"... Label wont take my string?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I want my label object to display a string or an integer, but I can't seem to find the problem

```
"System::Windows::Forms::Label::Text::set" cannot be called with the given argument list
```

argument types are (`std::string`)

Function type is `System::Windows::Forms::Label^`
[image]

Scroll to the very end of my program to see what I'm talking about

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int result;



namespace PraythisWorksOMG {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(74, 102);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(98, 34);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(74, 169);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(74, 12);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(74, 58);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(88, 212);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(46, 17);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(282, 253);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {


        int number;
        int radix;
        try
        {
            number = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
            radix = Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
        }
        catch (...) // catch all Convert errors
        {

            MessageBox::Show("this isn't string");

        }
        if (radix < 2 || radix > 36)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("must be integers!");
        }
        else
        {
            do // conversion algorithm
            {
                char digit = number % radix;
                number /= radix;
                if (digit > 9) // for letters
                {
                    digit += 7; // add bias
                }
                digit += 0x30; // convert to ASCII
                result = digit + result;
            } while (number != 0);
        }






        std::string test = "test";
        label1->Text = "Test";
        label1->Text = test;




    }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is C# not C++ - do not confuse these two very different languages.

Comment: @ALX23z It is not C#. It is C++/CLI aka Managed C++.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your std::string to System::String. You can do it with:

```
label1->Text = gcnew System::String(test.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET classes do not interact with `std::string`, an unmanaged C++ standard library type.

[It's looking for a `System::String`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.text?view=netframework-4.8)

You generally don't want `std::string` in your managed code.

By the way, C++/CLI is on its way out. Why not use some lovely C# for this project?